# Is it possible to integrate google analytics 360 to a data warehouse without Bigquery

Tags: google-analytics, integration, etl, data-warehouse

One of our clients wonders if they can get raw data from google analytics 360 to their own data warehouse directly.

I believe it's impossible by reading up many materials **but I just couldn't find it's official document or notice which enunciates that it's impossible.**

Does anyone know what I am looking for?
If so, please leave a comment with the pagelink.

Many thanks in advance! :)